# What is the "Root" of a Graphql Field Resolver supposed to be?

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

Using TypeGraphql we can write a resolvers and field resolvers. 99% of the time we are returning something directly or even indirectly from the database. Some object or document. So when we write field resolvers to add additional data, what is the intended type of the `root` argument? The exact type of value we returned from the main query (such as a DB document) or the graphql type?

```
@Resolver(() => EventType)
export class EventResolver {
  
  @Query(() => EventType)
  async events(): Promise<EventType[]> {
    const events = await EventModel.find().lean();
    return events;
  }

  @FieldResolver(() => Boolean) 
  async isActive(@Root() root: ???): Promise<boolean> {
    // Here root will most definitely be the entire result of EventModel.find()
    // So does it make more sense to define root as Event (the model definition) or EventType
    return datechecker(root.date)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the database type. The db might have fields (columns) that are not exposed in the GraphQL type but are of use to field resolvers.

I have such an example where in the db I have a date field `verified_at` but that field is not exposed in the GraphQL schema. Instead there's an `isVerified` (Boolean) field that is just `!!verified_at`. I can count on `verified_at` being present in the root after the parent object is resolved and yet know that GraphQL will ultimately strip it from the final result returned to the client.

Comment: It feels both right and wrong to me. I finally found [this documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains) about resolver chains and based on this it seems that the expected value for "parent" (or "root" in typegraphql) would be the main resolver type, but in practice not only is that no the case (usually) but also makes life more difficult. If the root actually returned the stripped-down database result we'd lose access to some fields we may not be returning through the type like you said (verified_at).